# Cannot send Highcharts to back (z-index) of page

Tags: css, highcharts

I'm trying to send the Highcharts generated graph to the background (so I can overlay a menu item at the top of the page). How can I make this happen?

Relevant CSS:

```
#chart { 
  min-width: 400px; 
  max-width: 1400px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  z-index: -999 !Important; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do you have? z-index should work without problems if you have assigned a position other than static on the element

Comment: I've tried setting the z-index of the div that the chart is in, the wrapper div for the chart, nothing seems to move it back. I don't have any of my elements static, either. Relevant CSS: #chart {
 min-width: 400px;
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: -999 !Important;
}

Comment: Relevant screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/3b2V3g2j0r0a

Comment: Please provided code or a jsFiddle the reproduces the problem.  A snippet of CSS isn't enough.

Comment: I've also tried z-index at 0. Sorry about the lack of code, here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wvN4d/

Comment: @Boaz Negative z-index values are totally legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are setting your z-index on the `chart` div and not it's parent container `content`:

```
<div id="content" style="z-index:-1">
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvN4d/1/).

[image]